# Multiselect prodct's attribute

Tags: magento, export, custom-attribute

I have created a new multi select type attribute from admin in magento using **manage attribute** section and used back end source model for label and  value.

Now when I export the product csv from admin using export all data profile than my multi select attribute shows blank. i want to show selected value in csv.

**My source model code:**

```
<?php
    class CityVal_City_Model_Product_Attribute_Unit extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
    {
      public function getAllOptions()
      {
        $connection = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $sql = 'SELECT  city_id,city_name FROM cities';
        $orders = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        foreach($orders as $ord)
        {
            $customerArr[] = array(
                           'value' => $ord['city_id'],
                           'label' => $ord['city_name'],
                            );
        }
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = $customerArr;
        }
        return $this->_options;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

**After foreach we have value in  multi select city drop down in admin. i am unale to post image otherwise,  i post a image**

Comment: I think you need to include more details. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  [mcve] and(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Please show us what do you have in $customerArr after foreach?

Comment: I mean show us var_dump($customerArr)

Comment: @zhartaunik  this is my var_dump($customerArr):-                          array(715) { [0]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> string(1) "1" ["label"]=> string(6) "ABOHAR" } [1]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> string(1) "2" ["label"]=> string(8) "Abu Road" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to export multi select attribute then go to system -> import/export -> dataflow - profiles and export product by select your store.
You will find multiselect attribute with value which product have selected in csv file.

Comment: i don't get selected value in csv.  i am getting multiselect attribute blank for product.

Comment: go to admin panel catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes -> select your attribute and "manage label" add there label for all store views if you have multiple store views. if not worked then create new multiselect attribute and try it. multiselect attribute export funationality in magento is default.

Comment: it can not work with dynamic value. how can i add option and value in attribute dynamically.